# How to make a black and white pattern colored roulette wheel?

Tags: javascript

This is how my roulette wheel look like at the moement. im trying to make the color instead of rainbow into black and white repetitively.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOP3V.png

this is the code:

```
var options = ["3x Candy", "1x Candy", "1x candy[![enter image description here][1]][1]", "1x Candy", "2x Candy", "3x Candy", "5xCandy", "2x Candy", "5x Candy",];

var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
var spinTimeout = null;

var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 0;
var spinTimeTotal = 0;

var ctx;

document.getElementById("spin").addEventListener("click", spin);

function byte2Hex(n) {
  var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F,1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F,1);
}

function RGB2Color(r,g,b) {
    return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
}

function getColor(item, maxitem) {
  var phase = 0;
  var center = 128;
  var width = 127;
  var frequency = Math.PI*2/maxitem;
  
  red   = Math.sin(frequency*item+2+phase) * width + center;
  green = Math.sin(frequency*item+0+phase) * width + center;
  blue  = Math.sin(frequency*item+4+phase) * width + center;
  
  return RGB2Color(red,green,blue);
}

function drawRouletteWheel() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var outsideRadius = 240;
    var textRadius = 180;
    var insideRadius = 0;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);

    //ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    //ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    ctx.font = '15px Quicksand, sans-serif';

    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
      //ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
      ctx.fillStyle = getColor(i, options.length);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
      ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);

      //ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.save();
      //ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      //ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      //ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
      //ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 
                    250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
      ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      var text = options[i];
      ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
      ctx.restore();
    } 

    //Arrow
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function spin() {
  spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
  spinTime = 0;
  spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
  rotateWheel();
}

function rotateWheel() {
  spinTime += 30;
  if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
    stopRotateWheel();
    return;
  }
  var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
  startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
  drawRouletteWheel();
  spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
}

function stopRotateWheel() {
  clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
  var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
  var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
  var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = '30px Quicksand, sans-serif';
  var text = options[index]
  ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
  ctx.restore();
}

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
  var ts = (t/=d)*t;
  var tc = ts*t;
  return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
}

drawRouletteWheel();
```

ps: i dont write this codes i got it from google and only edited them a little

im really sorry if this problem seems really vague. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colors by modifying value of `ctx.fillStyle`.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
  // Below's value shows the color of plate.
  // Modify the color value as you want
  ctx.fillStyle = i % 2 === 1 ? '#eee' : '#000';

  ...

  // And the fillStyle comes next shows the font color.
  // Modify the color value as you want.
  ctx.fillStyle = i % 2 === 1 ? '#000' : '#fff';

  ...
}
```

Then modify the `options` Array to be even length to eliminate the situation of appearing same color twice in roulette.